# Find location of oracle_home from java

Tags: java, oracle

What would be the best way to find oracle home and tnsnames.ora from java?
Actually i am trying to get a list of tns entries and display it in program combobox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no some automatic search. If you want Oracle's JDBC driver to use your tns names, you have to define system property (-D) `oracle.net.tns_admin=<directory where tnsnames.ora is located>`. I recommend setting it up so you can use it and `ojdbc` will be use it too (if needed)

Comment: Does `oracle.net.tns_admin` work if set at runtime using `System.setProperty` or is it required that the parameter is set when launching the application?

Comment: For you to use it, you simply have to make sure it is setup before you need it. OJDBC, i believe needs it in some `static` initializer and to be available to it, you have to make sure it is setup before ojdbc classes are loaded (but this is hard, so the safest is to put it on command line - you need this if you want to use tnsnames for oracle connections)

Comment: Right before `Class.forName()` isn't early enough then? Naturally, things get even trickier when frameworks are introduced to handle drivers and connections.

Answer (score 1):

tnsnames.ora is in `ORACLE_HOME/network/admin`. Code would be:

```
String oracleHome = System.getenv("ORACLE_HOME");
if(oracleHome != null){
     String tnsFilename = oracleHome + File.separatorChar + 
                       "network" + File.separatorChar + 
                       "admin" + File.separatorChar + 
                       "tnsnames.ora";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've `ORACLE_HOME` set as an envinroment variable then you can use `System.getenv("ORACLE_HOME");` to access it.

See [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html).